# jquery slideDown - sliding down more than required and then reversing

Tags: jquery, jquery-effects

Here is my code

```
$.get("insert-note.exec.php", {mess: messIn}, function(ajaxContent) {
   if(ajaxContent != 0) {    
      $('#message-text').val('');  
      $('#insert-flag').after(ajaxContent);  
      $('#insert-flag').next('.message-bubble').slideDown('slow');
   }
});
```

CSS Part

```
#message-text {
 padding:4px;
 outline:none;
 color:#FFF;
 border:3px solid #101010;
 background-color:#FFF;
 border-radius:6px;
 -moz-border-radius:6px;
}    

.message-bubble {
 width:92%;
 padding:1.50%;
 margin-bottom:2%;
 letter-spacing:1px;
 border-radius:8px;
 overflow:hidden;
 cursor:pointer;
 -moz-border-radius:8px;
 background-color:#FFF;
 -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFF;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFF;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFF;
}

#insert-flag {
  width:0;
  height:0;
}
```

In short, I am trying to fetch data (ajax) from server which is returned as a div and I am trying to slide the div into the current interface.

**Problem**: It all works as expected except that the new div slides a little extra lower and then recovers to the appropriate size.

**For example**: For a 3-line div, the effect results in an initial `slideDown` of, let say, 5-lines and then akin to a effect of `slideUp` adjusts itself to the appropriate 3-lines.

How can I handle this?

(Note: A similar effect can be seen at [Loopt](https://www.loopt.com/) which works properly when new content is pushed)

Comment: I don't see any issues with the javascript/jquery.  I suspect the problem is likely in the css for the elements you're using.  Can you post that as well?

Comment: It sounds like your jQuery is having problems with detecting the elements height. I think this could be fixed with a little delay. Meaning, that jQuery would have enough time to understand your element and sort of *buffer* it. And then display it.

Comment: @Kalle It happens even with `.delay()'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly well known bug with jQuery's slide methods. It occurs when the div being slided does not have a defined height. Perhaps using .delay() as suggested in a comment will work. But another, possibly more robust solution, is that you first make the div that will get filled with the response data have a style like `position:absolute; visibility:hidden`. This will allow you to get the height of the div without the user initially seeing the content.

So something like:

```
<style>
.message-bubble {position:absolute; visibility:hidden}
</style>

<script>
$.get("insert-note.exec.php", {mess: messIn}, function(ajaxContent) {
   if(ajaxContent != 0) {    
      $('#message-text').val('');  
      $('#insert-flag').after(ajaxContent);
      var newContent = $('#insert-flag').next('.message-bubble');

     //set an inline style attribute to the correct height, and prepare the div for slideDown()
      newContent.css({
           height:newContent.height() + 'px',
           display:'none',
           visibility:'visible'
           position:'relative',
      });
      newContent.slideDown('slow');
   }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but things only seem to be working fine when `height:` property is set. Otherwise, nothing much is gained.

Comment: Um... That's exactly my point. That is why I initially set the div to have visibility:hidden (so that the height can be dynamically calculated) and position absolute (so that the hidden div does not interfere with the layout flow). Once that is done, the div is changed to a visibility of visible, with display none, and position relative (i.e., resetting the div to the real properties you want). But from the previous step, we are also able to define the correct height, which eliminates the jumpiness.

Answer (score 0):

Most cases of jQuery being jumpy are related to the dimensions of the elements. JQuery doesn't basically understand where your element ends. SlideDown will basically keep going, until, "OH NO!" I went too far.. then corrects it.

I'm not quite sure, which element is the main container in your case. But you must add solid width or height values. If your are sliding them down, then most likely the important part is the height. This might be pretty annoying, if your containers content is dynamic.. but it will definitely fix your jumpy problem. Of course, there is always a chance that it doesn't. In that case publish more code, so we could look for a more localized issue.

Also it might be related to your paddings and `width: 92%;`. I recommend to try to remove the paddings and your %-width, for debugging purposes. Also you can achieve your "little-bit-less-then-100%" with `display: block;` + `padding: ...;`.

Comment: What doesn't work? My answers point was the dimensions of the element -- height. If it works by setting the height attribute, then i'm correct. However, if you want to have the elements content more dynamic.. and without a static height, then you must look for a more advance solution. As I said, the problem might be anywhere.. You could start by including your example site..